# `getOrCreateObject3D` has been deprecated. Use `setObject3D()` and `object3dset` event instead

Tags: three.js, aframe, 8thwall-web

I'm working on a project on [8th Wall](https://www.8thwall.com/) using A-Frame and Three.js. I'm using a component called ["text-geometry"](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/text-geometry) which generates extruded text.

But I keep getting this warning:

```
`getOrCreateObject3D` has been deprecated. Use `setObject3D()` and `object3dset` event instead.
```

The code from the component is:

```js
const mesh = el.getOrCreateObject3D('mesh', THREE.Mesh)
```

What should I replace this with? Neither `setObject3D()` nor `object3dset` works.

Comment: it looks like [getOrCreateObject3D was deprecated back in 2017](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/3222) but the component you are using is [still using it](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/text-geometry/index.js#L32). Maybe search or post an issue in the [component library issue queue](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/issues)

Comment: Yes but the question is what is the proper replacement for that command? Deprecated how? What's the new method?